# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 1

Tags: python, csv, unicode

This is my first post here excuse me if i miss anything.
I have some data in my CSV file and am trying to import data into my prod and getting UnicodeDecodeError. I have some french words in my csv file

Code:

```
open_csv = csv.DictReader(open('filename',''rb))
   for i in open_csv:
   x = find(where={})#mongodb query
   x.something = i.get(row_header)
   x.save()
```

am getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 1  error while saving the data

Comment: Here is my code                                                                                open_csv = csv.DictReader(open('filename',''rb))
for i in open_csv:
    x = find(where={})#mongodb query
    x.something = i.get(row_header)
    x.save()

Comment: I suspect it's because the file isn't UTF-8. Try decoding with `'mbcs'`.

Comment: Edit that code into your question; it's nigh unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Or `latin-1` (ISO standard) or `cp1252` (Windows modified `latin-1`), given it's Western European text, or `utf-16` if it was Unicode output from a Windows program.

Comment: @shadowRanger2 : I tried using latin-1 but still am getting the same error.

Comment: Which line of code is giving you the error? You should copy/paste the *entire* error message list.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `'mbcs'` is just a shorthand for whatever codepage the current system is configured for.

Comment: 0x8e in CP-1252 is Ž; I wouldn't expect that in French text. It's in the C1 control code range in ISO-8859-1, so that doesn't seem right either. It's À in CP-863, which might be a bit more likely. @Kashyap What's the first accented letter in that file supposed to look like?

Comment: @ Mark Ransom Am getting that error while am saving it.

Comment: @ ephemient : this is the french word bébés

Comment: What part of "copy/paste" are you having trouble understanding? This is vital information when dealing with a Python error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the following code:

```
 import codecs
 open_csv = csv.DictReader(codecs.open('filename','rb'))
 for i in open_csv:
     x = find(where={})
     x.something = i.get(row_header)
     x.save()
```

I work in Python 3.x but this should work in 2.x too if that is what you are using.

Comment: One of the biggest differences between Python 2 and 3 is the way it handles Unicode. I wouldn't assume *anything*.

Comment: @sleepcoffeedelight : I tried using codecs but still am getting the same error.